# What image sizes should I use for a mobile cross-platfom game?

Tags: monogame, mobile, cross-platform, resolution

I'm new to mobile development. I use Monogame.

What device screen resolutions should I consider to target all Android, iOS and Windows Phone devices?

Assuming we have three screen sizes, should I be using different images for each target resolution?

Comment: What have you tried? Is your game 2D or 2D, immense MMORPG or a modestly-sized platformer? It's difficult to answer such a general question.

Comment: 2D or 2D ? do you mean, 2D or 3D ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would at least make a difference between high resolution and low resolution devices. 
You should also distinguish between tablets and phones.

Another important factor is the difference in the aspect ratio. You have 4:3 16:9 and other device formats.

For some explanation on iOS devices look here:
http://www.codeandweb.com/blog/2012/12/14/scaling-content-for-retina-display-iphone-and-ipad

Answer (score 1):

Mobile devices can have all kinds of screen resolutions, from small low-end phones to large tablets. While the available resolutions on iOS are manageable, the markets for Android and Windows Phone devices is so fragmented that you can get pretty much anything.

That means you should try to develop as resolution-independent as possible. When you can, you should develop your game in a way that it checks the screen resolution and automatically resize the graphics accordingly, so that the part of the game world shown on each device is the same.